# (Einer Sache / einem Umstand) Rechnung tragen

Tags: translation, grammatical-case

While doing my translation exercises, I came across this use of *Rechnung tragen* on [page 12 of this annual report](https://www.mvb.de/content/dam/f0580-0/webn/Publikationen/geschaeftsberichte/MVB-Gesch%C3%A4ftsbericht_2014.pdf):

> Während die Zahl der Bankstellen bundesweit rückläufig ist, hat die
>   Mainzer Volksbank unverändert eine flächendeckende Marktpräsenz. Mit
>   36 personenbesetzten Zweigstellen und 43 SB-Stellen wird **dem
>   Rechnung getragen**.

Although I understand the second sentence ("*This is because of the 36 branches...*" or "*This is taking into account the 36 branches...*"), my question is: what noun is ***dem*** referring to? *Rechnung*, *Marktpräsenz*, *Bankstellen*, are all feminine, and I don't see any other candidate.

Comment: The title is misleading, for the question actually concerns the demonstrative pronoun *der* rather than the phrase *Rechnung tragen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Dem* referres to *what was said*.

> [Damit wird] *diesem Umstand* / *diesem Sachverhalt* / *dem zuvor Erwähnten* / *dem zuvor Gesagten* Rechnung getragen.

Comment: Das, wie auch den zitierten Satz, halte ich für falsch. Die Marktpräsenz drückt sich in Zweigstellen und SB-Stellen aus. "Unser Ziel ist Kundennähe. MIt ... Zweigstellen ... wird dem Rechnung getragen." Wem? Dem letzten Satz sicher nicht. Dem Ziel. Der Umstand kann sein, dass eine ältere Bevölkerung mehr Kundennähe wünscht. Dem trägt man Rechnung mit vielen Filialen. Aber diese sind ja die Marktpräsenz, können dieser also nicht Rechnung tragen.

Comment: @userunknown Die Zweigstellen sind nicht - wie von dir fälschlicherweise gleichgesetzt - die Marktpräsenz. Es gibt Banken mit sehr hoher Marktpräsenz, die überhaupt keine Filialen haben. Das Zitat ist ein abgeschlossener Absatz direkt nach der Überschrift *Investitionen*. Der zweite Satz bezieht sich eindeutig auf den ersten. Dem dort genannten Fakt wird mit den Investitionen in Filialen Rechnung getragen.

Comment: Ich setze sie nicht gleich, sondern sage, dass hier die Marktpäsenz in Filialen und Bankomaten besteht. Das schließt andere Möglichkeiten nicht aus, auch wenn mir, bezugnehmend auf das "flächendeckend" nur wenige Alternativen einfallen. Und die Investitionen in Filialen liest Du da rein, es steht da aber nicht. "Unserem Ziel die Markpräsenz auszubauen wurde mit 3 neuen Filialen und 7 Bankomaten Rechnung getragen" - das wäre eine sinnvolle Formulierung gewesen.

Comment: @userunknown 1. "...mit vielen Filialen. Aber diese sind ja die Marktpräsenz..." du setzt sie also sehr wohl gleich. 2. Einfach mal den verlinkten Originaltext öffnen. Im Gegensatz zu dir lese ich da überhaupt nichts *rein*. Von "unserem Ziel" steht da überhaupt nichts. Das liest du da rein.

Comment: a) Im konkreten Fall besteht die Marktpräsenz in Filialen und Automaten. Falls noch weiteres dazu gehört so ist davon hier zumindest nicht die Rede. Es ist nur nicht ausgeschlossen. b) Doch, Investitionen liest Du da rein. Ich dagegen habe nicht "Ziel" hineingelesen, sondern behauptet, dass wenn von einem Ziel die Rede gewesen wäre, dann könnte man schreiben, diesem Ziel sei mit ... Rechnung getragen worden. Dass es eben nicht da steht ist der Angelpunkt meiner Argumentation, den ich verlöre, läse ich die Ziele da rein.